# I want to stop my net beans projects from opening in internet explorer

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Java in Netbeans. I was working on a class project and I unintentionally typed some letters in the editor window and click some keys that made my project suddenly open in internet explorer. I tried to reset the settings of net beans and I tried uninstalling and reinstalling NetBeans but my projects all keep opening in internet explorer. I tried looking up information on how to fix this problem but I can not find any information on this and I have very minimal knowledge about NetBeans. Can some please help me make my project open inside of NetBeans?

Comment: Not clear what file you're opening. Search for "default applications" in the start menu, or right click the file, and go to properties, then open with NetBeans

Comment: Thank you, for your help, I think I somehow fixed it.